# How to get link of <h3> in a Website with BeautfulSoup4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am currently writing a script that gets all the content of the website http://www.xetra.com/xetra-en/newsroom/xetra-newsboard with BeautifulSoup4. So far I have managed to get all the announcement in a list with:

```
gdata_even=soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list2Col even "})
gdata_odd=soup.find_all("li", {"class":"list2Col odd "})
```

However I am struggling to get the link (url) which is emebedded in the href. 
.
.
.
.
.

```
 <div class="contentCol">
                 <div class="categories">
                  Frankfurt
                 </div>
                 <h3>
                  <a href="/xetra-en/newsroom/xetra-newsboard/FRA-Deletion-of-Instruments-from-XETRA---24.08.2015-001/1909774">
                   FRA:Deletion of Instruments from XETRA - 24.08.2015-001
                  </a>
                 </h3>
                </div>
```

Can someone assist please

THanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itzmeontv answered your question but the answer to your comment is this:

```
for matchDiv in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "contentCol"}):
    h3Url = matchDiv.find("a").get("href")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
.find_all('a',href=True)[0]['href'] # first element
```

OR

using `for loop`

```
for i in soup.find_all('a',href=True):
    print i['href']
```

**Update**

```
for i in soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class" : "contentCol"}):
    for j in i.find_all("h3"):
        for k in j.find_all('a',href=True):
            print k['href']
```

Comment: This would give me all the links that are on the page...however I just need the link in class "contentCol" -> for <h3>